# Can I connect to SSAS remotely without running IIS on the machine

Tags: angularjs, ssas

We would like to use a pivot grid web control in an angular SPA to connect to a SSAS cube but the only way I found it is using XMLA which requires IIS to be running on the same machine as the analysis server. We don't want to use IIS. Is there another way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: To validate, you have already been able to connect from angular SPA to an SSAS cube using XMA via `MSMDPUMP.DLL`?

Comment: No, I have not tried that yet since that is not an option for us.

Comment: Got it, the reason I asked is because XMLA is usually used for SSAS administrative / operational tasks vs executing queries using MDX.  Would you be able to utilize MDX via ODBC?